# Need to sanity-check my .htaccess, especially Limit GET POST line for Google repellent

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, robots.txt, web-crawlers

I need a sanity check on this .htaccess (from a WordPress site) I inherited from a 5 month+ old site.
What's the symptom? Google + Bing crawl, but don't index any of the pages.
Let me be clear: I'm not mad about "not ranking high." I think something is (accidentally) rejecting search engine indexing.

I am not an expert on .htaccess, but one part especially looked funny, the **Limit GET POST** line. Is it not weird to have both Allow and Deny all, with no parameters?

Also, I've ruled out robots.txt, but if I were you I'd want to see it, so here it is:

```
User-agent:  *
Crawl-delay:  30
```

And here's the more suspect .htaccess:

```
# temp redirect wordpress content feeds to feedburner
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedBurner    [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedValidator [NC]
RewriteRule ^feed/?([_0-9a-z-]+)?/?$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/anonymousblog  [R=302,NC,L]
</IfModule>

# temp redirect wordpress comment feeds to feedburner
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedBurner    [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !FeedValidator [NC]
RewriteRule ^comments/feed/?([_0-9a-z-]+)?/?$    http://feeds.feedburner.com/anonymous_comments [R=302,NC,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

php_value memory_limit 32M
```

Adding header by request:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<meta name="description" content="buncha junk i've deleted." />
<meta name="keywords" content="keywords i've deleted" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your website's header code too. You want to make sure you're **not** doing something silly like this:

`<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">`

Comment: Added it, and boy it does look suspicious! According to what I just Googled, you're right on the money. But why the heck didn't Google Webmaster Tools mention it...

Comment: Delete this line:

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />`

...and you're good to go. [If there is no robots <META> tag the default is "INDEX,FOLLOW".](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html)